# Finding the image of another operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}$ and define  $T_{n}:\ell_{2} \rightarrow \ell_{2}$ by $$T_{n}(x) = (\frac{x_{n}}{n},\frac{x_{n + 1}}{n + 1},... ).$$

where $x = (x_{1},x_{2},.....).$

Then,$$T_{n}^{*}(x) = (0,...,0,\frac{x_{1}}{n},\frac{x_{2}}{n + 1},... ).$$
 Where the zeros in the adjoint are $n-1$ times.

Is ker $T_{n} = \{0\}$? what about Im $T_{n}^{*}$?  Could anyone help me in finding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathrm{ker}(T_n)=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\mid x_k=0~\forall~k\ge n\}$$
$$\mathrm{Im}(T_n^{\star})=(\mathrm{ker}(T_n))^{\perp}=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\mid  x_k=0~\forall~1\le k<n\}$$

Comment: what about the image?

Comment: Use the fact that the image of the adjoint operator is othocomplement of the kernel of the operator.

Comment: you mean orthogonal complement .....right ? I know this fact but do not know the details of using it.